# how to create one login in jsp so that it does not ask for loginid after login?

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have created a jsp login page and it is working well. As I login it opens a menu having apply, print options the problem is that I need to pass login id again to perform these operation. I have used session but the problem with session is that I have used jsp forward to pass a session variable. The value is preserved for one forward request after that it becomes null. How can I preserve a login ID so that I did not need to enter again and again?

```
try{
        int loginid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("loginid"));
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from login where loginid=? AND password=?");
        ps.setInt(1, loginid);
        ps.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        PreparedStatement prs=con.prepareStatement("select email from login where loginid=?");

        prs.setInt(1,loginid);
        ResultSet rst=prs.executeQuery();
        String email="";
        if(rst.next())
        {
            email=rst.getString("email");
            session.setAttribute("email",email);
        }

        session.setAttribute("email",email);
        //out.println(session);
        session.setAttribute("Login",loginid);
        if(rs.next())
        {

        %>
        <jsp:forward page="loginMediate.jsp"></jsp:forward>
        <%}else
        {%>
            <script> alert("Invalid Details")</script>
        <%}
        }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

options after login

```
  <table >
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top">
<br><br>
<button onclick="location.href='loginDetails.jsp'" class="mybutton" type="button" style="width: 200px; height: 37px;">
     APPLICATION FORM</button>
<br><br><br><br>
<!-- <button onclick="location.href='edit.jsp'" class="mybutton" type="button" style="width: 200px; height: 37px;">
     FINAL SUBMIT</button>
  <br><br><br><br>    -->
<button onclick="location.href='printLogin.jsp'" class="mybutton" type="button" style="width: 200px; height: 37px;">
     PRINT FORM</button>
 <br><br><br><br>
<button onclick="location.href='logout.html'" class="mybutton" type="button" style="width: 200px; height: 37px;">
     LOGOUT</button>     
</td>
<td>     

<img src="pics/login.jpg" style="height:500px;"class="imgDes">

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

how to access session variable in loginDetails. when I acess session variables email and loginid it gives null values.I have also tried to use previous session but it does not work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: you can store the values in Application or context scope. This will be accessible throughout all pages.

Comment: but How can I create a context scope dynamically

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to show a minimal working example that illustrates your problem so that we can better help you.